# How to incrementally add multiple model outputs to a DF in an automated way?

Tags: r, dplyr, automation, data-wrangling

For exploratory purposes, I'm running `156` different regression models. For each model, I extract `AIC`, `BIC`, `logLik` and `R²`.

Copying each metric for each model (624x CtrlC/V) and pasting to an Excel blank file simply feels very dumb - because it is.

**QUESTION: Does anyone have a tip on how to code a workaround for this time wasting work?** Maybe elucidating how I could sequentially add it to a new data frame.

**Code example:**

```
a <- lmer(y ~ covariate¹ + ... + covariateⁿ + Time + (1 + Time | ID))
AIC(a)
BIC(a)
logLik(a)
r.squaredGLMM(a)
```

Thanks. Cheers

**EDIT:** I mean, I know identifying them might be a concern (like some sorts of model in different columns), but in this case whatever. If I got a DF of 156 lines x 4 columns (4 metrics of interest per model) I would already be happy.

Comment: Have a look at the glance function in the package broom.mixed. This already gives you a bunch of stats. Now you could just loop through all your models and store their glance outcome in a data frame where each model represents a row. This is probably pretty automized then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titorelli you probably solved this now, but this might help others in future.

I realise answers that just reference links are not great for SO, but I suggest looking at Hadley's [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) book, Chapter 25 *Many Models*. Hadley explictly looks at dealing with many models using list-columns and also references broom (like [deschen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2725773/deschen) did above):

> In this chapter you’re going to learn three powerful ideas that help
> you to work with large numbers of models with ease:
>
> 1 Using many simple models to better understand complex datasets.
>
> 2 Using list-columns to store arbitrary data structures in a data frame.
> For example, this will allow you to have a column that contains linear
> models.
>
> 3 Using the broom package, by David Robinson, to turn models into tidy
> data. This is a powerful technique for working with large numbers of
> models because once you have tidy data, you can apply all of the
> techniques that you’ve learned about earlier in the book.

I don't want to replicate his book, the examples are well laid out, but look at *25.2.4 Model Quality* which uses `purr` to map models and `broom` to get to what you want.(Using gapminder as example.)

```
by_country %>% 
  mutate(glance = map(model, broom::glance)) %>% 
  unnest(glance)

#> # A tibble: 142 x 17 
#> # Groups:   country, continent [142]   
#>   country continent data  model resids r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic   
#>   <fct>   <fct>     <lis> <lis> <list>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Afghan… Asia      <tib… <lm>  <tibb…     0.948         0.942 1.22      181.    
#> 2 Albania Europe    <tib… <lm>  <tibb…     0.911         0.902 1.98      102.    
#> 3 Algeria Africa    <tib… <lm>  <tibb…     0.985         0.984 1.32      662.    
#> # … with 136 more rows, and 8 more variables: p.value <dbl>, df <dbl>,  
#> #   logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```